# Primefaces Dataexporter and get method

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

With a simple class wich contains only a list of list of String, I can view all its elements in a `p:dataTable` with the `get(int)` method of class List but it fails when I try to export this with the `p:dataExporter` component.

Here's the Java source code :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MainClass {

private List<ArrayList<String>> listOfListOfString;

public List<ArrayList<String>> getListOfListOfString() {
    return listOfListOfString;
}

public void setListOfListOfString(List<ArrayList<String>> listOfListOfString) {
    this.listOfListOfString = listOfListOfString;
}

public MainClass() {
    listOfListOfString = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
    firstList.add("a");
    firstList.add("b");
    listOfListOfString.add(firstList);
    ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();
    secondList.add("1");
    secondList.add("2");
    listOfListOfString.add(secondList);
}
}
```

And the XTHML code :

```
    <h:body>
    Hello from Facelets
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="myList" value="#{mainClass.listOfListOfString}" paginator="true" rows="10" > 
            <p:column headerText="First column"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{myList.get(0)}"/>
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Second column">  
                <h:outputText value="#{myList.get(1)}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <h:commandLink  value=" csv">
            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tbl" fileName="userList" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And the error stack when I click on the csv link:

```
For input string: "get"
- Stack Trace

 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "get"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:173)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.getType(ListELResolver.java:72)
```

Do you have an idea why `p:dataTable` can use the `get(int)` method and `p:dataExporter` can't?

Thanks,

Philippe

Answer (score 2):

Probably both components are implemented differently.

But you can access list elements this way:

```html
#{myList[n]}
```

where `n` is the list index.

Comment: Perfect. It works! But it is strange that the get() method can't be used for an List object.

Comment: Good to hear. Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted (click on the checkmark left to the question).